# Sending messages to page Javascript from a content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, content-script

I have a method in the Javascript runtime for a tab that I want to fire from my extension's content script. At face value, this calls for message passing between contexts, but I cannot find any documentation of CS-to-tab messages, only tab-to-CS or CS-to-background. Essentially I want to flip the [Communication with the embedding page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication) section of the content scripts reference.

So far, I am attaching an event listener to the tab's `window` by injecting a small Javascript payload (this will trigger the tab method on the correct type of message):

```
listenerScript = document.createElement('script');
listenerScript.textContent = "window.addEventListener('message',function(ev){console.log('New event: ' + ev);},false);console.log('installed');";
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(listenerScript);
listenerScript.remove();
```

This listener is registered, however I can't figure out how to trigger it from my content script. `window.postMessage()` in the content script doesn't seem to do anything, and the documentation only talks about using `chrome.runtime` to create a port, which is for background scripts.

How do I pass messages, in the simplest way possible, from content script to tab?

Comment: The documentation you've linked shows `window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Hello from the webpage!" }, "*");` and it works for me. Just don't forget the `"*"`.

Comment: From a content script? I tried that exact code you quoted with the snippet above injected into the page, and it is not logging anything. Remember that I am trying to go `CS->page`, not `page->CS`.

Comment: Here is my test extension: https://github.com/redbassett/extension-message-test

I see the log messages for the injected script being installed and the message being sent, but the event listener never triggers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is correct, so, considering you see `installed` in the console, the only explanations are:

1. the page was redirected and the entire DOM and its listeners were destroyed.
2. the page has spoofed `window.addEventListener` or attached its own `'message'` listener and cancels the event before your listener sees it (e.g. by using `event.stopPropagation()` etc.)

   In this case you need to declare your content script to run [before the page starts loading](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at) and use a listener that captures the event before it bubbles down the DOM chain (`useCapture`, the 3rd parameter of `addEventListener`, should be `true`).

   manifest.json:

   ```
   "content_scripts": [{
       "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
       "js": ["content.js"],
       "run_at": "document_start"
   }],
   ```

   content.js:

   ```
   // this code runs before page starts loading
   var injected = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
   injected.text = '(' + function() {
       window.addEventListener('message', function(ev) {
           console.log('New event:', ev);
       }, true); // useCapture: true
       console.log('installed');
   } + ')()';
   injected.remove();

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       // this code will run when the DOM is ready
       window.postMessage({ foo: 'bar', text: "Hello from content script!" }, "*");
   });
   ```

   Note we add the script to `documentElement` because at `document_start` there's often no `head`.
   See also: [other methods of injecting a DOM script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/3959875).

Comment: That was an artifact of copying the code from another test. Good catch, but it still doesn't fix the issue. Pushed the correct version with `message` to the repo, still doesn't log anything in response to the message.

Comment: Using `'message'` the code works. As it should. Make sure the page isn't redirected to a new URL.

Comment: The redirect may be the issue! I tested this on a different host domain and the message shows. It would seem that the injected script is in fact being disconnected. Post as a new answer so I can accept it?